# can we store hundreds of thousands of data in a one document without any performance issue in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am new to mongodb. 
Need to know about the performance issue on fetching one document with **>5gb** related data.

my document structure:

```
{
    _id:100,

    question_id:200,

    analyze_data:[
       {
         date:20-01-1920,
         store_id:50,
         user_id:6,
       },
       .....,
       hundreds of thousands of records here 
       .....,
       {
         date:20-01-2015,
         store_id:6000,
         user_id:600000,
       },
      (nth number)
    ],
    graph_data:[
        {
         graph_id:5
         date:20-01-1920,
         store_id:50,
         user_id:6,
       },
       .....,
       hundreds of thousands of records here 
       .....,
       {
         date:20-01-2015,
         store_id:10000,
         user_id:400000,
       },
      (nth number)
    ]

}
```

I am having this type of document in my collection, I have to filter the **analyze_data** and **graph_data** according to the **date,store_id,user_id**.

After filtering I need to do some calculation and **restructure** my array.

```
{
    _id:100,

    question_id:200,

    analyze_data:[
       {
         date:20-01-1920,
         res:[
            {
             user_id:2,
             store_id:5,
             ......
            },
            {
             user_id:6,
             store_id:8,
             ......
            },
            (nth num)
         ]
       },
        {
         date:21-01-1999,
         res:[
            {
             user_id:644,
             store_id:66689,
             ......
            },
            {
             user_id:6455,
             store_id:877777,
             ......
            },
            (nth num)
            ]
       },
       ...............,
       ...............,
       ...............,
       (nth num)

    ],
    graph_data:[
        {
         date:20-01-1920,
         res:[
            {
             user_id:2,
             store_id:5,
             graph_details:{
              x_axis: [1,2,3,4,5,8,955,44,55,141],
              y_axis: [545,4545,77,55,88,228,822,5,22] 
             }
             ......
            },
            {
             user_id:6,
             store_id:8,
             graph_details:{
              x_axis: [154,2546,345,4456,5456,8456,955],
              y_axis: [545,4545,77,55,88,228,822,5,22] 
             }
             ......
            },
            (nth num)
         ]
       },
        {
         date:21-01-1999,
         res:[
            {
             user_id:644,
             store_id:66689,
             graph_details:{
              x_axis: [1,2,3,4,5,8,955,44,55,141],
              y_axis: [545,4545,77,55,88,228,822,5,22] 
             }
             ......
            },
            {
             user_id:6455,
             store_id:877777,
             graph_details:{
              x_axis: [1,2,3,4,5,8,955,44,55,141],
              y_axis: [545,4545,77,55,88,228,822,5,22] 
             }
             ......
            },
            (nth num)
            ]
       },
       ...............,
       ...............,
       ...............,
       (nth num)
    ]

}
```

The document having no limit.

**IMPORTANT**
How to use aggregate and map reduction in one connection using **mongodb-PHP** and working with multiple collection at a one instance.

Share any valuable recourse/post where I got cleared.

Is this the right way to store the related data?

1. Is this the right way to store data in mongo?
2. Is there any performance issue will occur?
3. What is the best way to reduce and restructure the output according
   to me?

Please provide me any valuable resources..

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by related data? Is your single document >5gb ?

Comment: @AbhayPS not so much but if it then can it handled?or any other solution?

Comment: Mongodb limit for document is 16MB and that is good enough for most cases. The size of War and Peace novel is less than 2MB. So, 16MB size is very big unless you store images,music,videos etc. in Mongodb. For such stuff there is GridFS in mongodb, so go ahead with mongodb. Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [MongoDB Document has a size limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) of 16 MB. You can use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) to exceed this limit, but internal your document is split to 16 MB chunks in put together on a look up. So your Queries should take a horrobile long amount of time.

I think it would be better to create a collection for every array in your document and add the the `question_id` and `_id` as `id_ref` (because the `_id` is a reserved key and all values have to be unique) to your array elements so the the can be identified.

```
Collection: analyze_data
{
  id_ref:100,
  question_id:200,
  date:20-01-1920,
  store_id:50,
  user_id:6,
},
...
{
  id_ref:100,
  question_id:200,
  date:20-01-2015,
  store_id:6000,
  user_id:600000,
},
etc. with other `id_ref`and `question_id`.
```

Analog collections for `graph_data`.

You can the use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to filter both collections by `date`, `store_id`, `user_id` and combine the results of both collections back to one document by the matching `ref_id` or `question_id`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to combine two or more collection after aggregation and do some calculation to find my required result at one request? Now i use map reduction do my calculation, as i know that its very slow then aggregation.